# Vue props update - You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

```js
Vue.component("step", {
        props: ["Model", "step"],
        data: function () {
            return {
                
            };
        },
        methods: {
            activateStep: function (step) {
                var vm = this;

                Vue.set(vm.Model, "ActiveStep", step);
            }
        }
});
```

```html
<step inline-template :model="Model" step=SomeStepNumber>

</step>
```

When I am trying to update vm.Model.ActiveStep it gives error saying - "**You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function**"

Comment: Where is activateStep being called?

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example which show how you use your component?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set the value(s) of properties within a component. Properties are set by the parent and passed into the component. The error is

```
Vue.set(vm.Model, "ActiveStep", step);
```

If the component needs to update its parent, the idiomatic approach is to emit an event to the parent

```
this.$emit("step", step)
```

and have that parent component update the property as appropriate.

If you need two-way binding, you can either use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) or the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)